# Import tables where the title contains the word "table" - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On the pages of that site, these tables appear 1 or 2 times on the right side, I would like to know if there is any way to tell `IMPORTXML` or `IMPORTHTML` to import the tables containing the word `"table"` such as: `"xxxxxxxxxx table"` and `"yyyyyyyyyyy table"`.

Because there are several tables on the page, if explain to the `IMPORT` which tables I am looking for, it would not need to import all of them.

Example Page:
https://int.soccerway.com/matches/2020/03/03/england/fa-cup/reading-fc/sheffield-united-fc/3221322/

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

> Obs.: The pages changes the number of tables according to the existing
> data, so I can't use something fixed like:

`=IMPORTHTML("LINK","table",9)`
`=IMPORTHTML("LINK","table",10)`

**Sheet link:**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dmql4y03xaJoh_wU01XoMM4b3ZSpF-biT7-qGXkyt7Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm a bit worry whether I could correctly understand about your goal. So if I misunderstood your goal and my proposal was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: If you can look at the updates I made to the question, now I think it has been better explained!

Comment: Thank you for replying. For your updated question, I added one more sample formula. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect again, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to use `IMPORTXML` or `IMPORTHTML` when "Championship table" and "Premier League table" are existing in the HTML data.
- You want to achieve this using the built-in formulas of Google Spreadsheet.

For this, how about this answer?

In this answer, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve the values of "Championship table" and "Premier League table" from the URL.
2. Join the retrieved values with `""` and compare it with `Championship tablePremier League table`.

   - When "Championship table" and "Premier League table" are existing, `TRUE` is returned.
   - From HTML data, I thought that the order of "Championship table" and "Premier League table" is the constant.

The sample formula is as follows. The URL is put to the cell "A1".

```
=IF(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTXML(A1,"//h2/a"))="Championship tablePremier League table",TRUE,FALSE)
```

- In this case, when "Championship table" and "Premier League table" are existing, `TRUE` is returned.

#### Sample formula:

When this formula is used, when "Championship table" and "Premier League table" are existing, as a sample, you want to use `IMPORTXML(A1,"//table/tr")`, it becomes as follows.

```
=IF(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IMPORTXML(A1,"//h2/a"))="Championship tablePremier League table",IMPORTXML(A1,"//table/tr"),"")
```

- The URL is put to the cell "A1".
- In this case, when "Championship table" and "Premier League table" are NOT existing, no values are shown.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

### Added:

For your updated question, how about the following answer?

From your question, I thought that when `xxxxxxxxxx table` and `yyyyyyyyyyy table` are existing, the 2 tables are existing. When I saw the HTML data, when `xxxxxxxxxx table` and `yyyyyyyyyyy table` are existing, it seems that the tables which has `leaguetable sortable table` as the class value are existing. I thought that this might be used for your situation. So how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=IF(AND(REGEXMATCH(INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1,"//h2/a"),1),"table"),REGEXMATCH(INDEX(IMPORTXML(A1,"//h2/a"),2),"table")),IMPORTXML(A1,"//table[contains(@class,'leaguetable sortable table')]//tr"),"")
```

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- In this case, `=IFERROR(IMPORTXML(A1,"//table[contains(@class,'leaguetable sortable table')]//tr"),"")` might be able to be used. About this, please test this for the case without the values of `xxxxxxxxxx table` and `yyyyyyyyyyy table`.

Comment: I updated the question, I think now it is better explained. Once again I'm sorry that you spent so much time explaining something that, due to my fault, was badly exemplified!